# On which Magento 1 CE version is the Professional version 1.9 base on?

Tags: magento-1.9

We run a deprecated Magento Professional version 1.9.1 and would like to upgrade to any other, supported version.

I think to know that both Magento EE and the Professional versions is/were forked off an existing community version.

Which CE version would come closest to the Professional version 1.9.1 in the regards to the code base (which implicitly means easiest upgrade path)?

Answer (score 0):

Magento Professional edition is not available now. It was discontinued many years ago. You have below options now:

- Upgrade to latest community edition 1.9.3.x (least efforts required)
- Upgrade to latest Magento community edition 2.1.x (require many efforts to transfer data and settings)
- Upgrade to Enterprise Edition 1.x (Yearly license will be applied)
- Upgrade to latest Magento Enterprise Edition 2.x (Yearly license will be applied)
- Upgrade to Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition 2.x (Magento owned hosted platform with features of Enterprise edition on a subscription basis)

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I believe the deprecated Professional 1.9.1 comes closer to some CE 1.4. CE 1.9.2 was released in July 2015, that is some 4 years later. Hence I doubt this is the version that comes closest to out Professional version.

Comment: In my opinion, since community edition is free, so you can play with Magento 1.9.3.x (which has better security features as compared to 1.9.2) before making any decision.

Comment: For now, I am only looking at which CE edition the Professional 1.9.1 was "forked". It must be somewhere around 1.4/5